# parent location reload at same scroll

Tags: javascript, parent-child

I'm not a programmer and I manage for work a web platform based on php+mysql with a prototype engine, where data form are opened/passed to server using the old modalbox script.
Until let's say one year ago or so after editing ora adding data in the modal window and closing it the parent page reloaded to the same scroll point I was.. and this was very useful because the platform generate very long data list.
Actually this don't work anymore and I'can't find the way to make it work.
Here's the code I use on the form closing button:

```
<a href="" onclick="Modalbox.hide( {afterHide: parent.location.reload()}); return false;">Continue</a>
```

I also add two infos:

- I've parent page list with anchor generated dinamically by a db query, that could be used in the child modal..
- could be great to avoid reload of page and update data dinamically, but may be this is another step beyond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiment I've found a custom function in the ajaxtabs.js and used it for applying a simple rewturn false;
so in the end here's the code

```
MYINSTANCE.onajaxpageload = function(pageurl) {
    return false;       
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use this JS function to reload or refresh current Url on body scroll

```
<body onscroll="location.reload();">
```

Comment: Platform uses prototype js system.. and I don't need to refresh on modal scroll but on modal close, and at the same scroll point I was when I opened the modal window. Thank for your answer

Comment: Ok I better understood the porblem: the ajax tab is inserting  data which ar enot in the source, so when I reload or click on an ajax call browser "don't know" the real height of the page due to the asyncronous behaviour.
I should use a script that understand the real scroll point of the page and send to it after reload. Any idea?